# Как отобразить блок при клике?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Имеется блок `<div id="block"></div>` и 5 ссылок `<a href='...' class='link'>Ссылка</a>`

Как сделать так, что бы по умолчанию при загрузке страницы блок был скрыт `display:none` и при нажатии на любую из ссылок блок появлялся и больше не пропадал.

Т.е. загружается страница - блока нет, нажал на ссылку 1 - блок с информацией появился, нажал на ссылку 2 - сменилась информация в блоке, нажал на ссылку 4 - снова сменилась информация. Блок постоянно активен

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, все просто:

```
$('.link').click(function () {
    $('#block').show();
});
```

Comment: а, главное, быстро) за 4 минуты и нашлось решение

Answer (score 0):

Очень интересно, вы задали вопрос и сами ответили, но ваш ответ не подходит для вашего вопроса. Минус поставлю я вам за ответ, и предложу свой вариант решения вашей задачи.

```js
'use strict';

function show(event) {
  var block = document.querySelector('#block');
  var target = event.target;

  if (!target.classList.contains('link')) return;

  if (block.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    block.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
  block.innerHTML = target.innerHTML;
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', show);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <div id="block" class="hidden"></div>
  <a href="#" class="link">Ссылка 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">Ссылка 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">Ссылка 3</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">Ссылка 4</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">Ссылка 5</a>
```